# Zero inflated binomial for excessive zeros

Tags: deep-learning, binomial-distribution, lstm, zero-inflation

**"What are some tricks for dealing with a zero inflated response variable when tackling a machine learning regression problem?"**

**Answer :**

*"One of the easiest and most intuitive methods is to run a two-model/stage regression.
Start by modeling the binary response (e.g. logistic, zero vs. non-zero)."*

---

[image]

That photo shows that we have a trend. However, the trend is not exceptional because there is too much zeros in the target set and the features.

**MSE Loss / criterion on data $(x,y)$**

**Current situation $(f(x) - y)^2$:**

1. The gradient is $(f(x) - y) \nabla(f(x))$.
2. If $y$ is $0$: $f(x)$ is pushed to $0$.

**Zero inflated (binomial) output:**

$$g(x) = Sigmoid(h(x))$$ in $[0,1]$

$$f(x) = Linear(h(x))$$

1. $g(x) * f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is real and $g(x)$ is $0$ or $1$. As $g$
   is not differentiable, then $g$ will simply be the sigmoid function.

   $$(g(x) * f(x) - y)^2$$
2. If $y$ and $g(x) = 0$, loss is $0$, I win
3. If $y$ = $0$ and $g(x) = 1$, it’s the same as above
4. If $y$ not $0$  and $g(x)=0$, this will affect $g(x)$, pushing it to
   not be $0$
5. If $y$ not $0$ and $g(x)=1$, I get valuable gradient information for
   $f(x)$

As mentioned at the beginning, it is necessary to build another model to predict g(x) and then insert it inside the model which predict f(x).

**QUESTIONs :**

1. Does "zero influted (binomial) output" can be the right solution to
   deal with my main problem? Otherwise, what is your suggestion?
2. Is there an existing piece of code that can help me to build the ML
   model for g?